# Can I call Swift URL Session from Kotlin Multiplatform?

Tags: swift, kotlin, design-patterns, repository-pattern, kotlin-multiplatform

I am working on an architecture where View is in Swift, VM in swift, however want to get the repository in Kotlin multiplatform.
[image: Similiar to this]

I understand immediate question would be why you want to separate network layer as KMM can handle this?. I don't want to loose the nativeness of network operations.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call native API of iOS from Kotlin, check this tutorial: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-objc-interop.html
(But then you need to have another realization for android via expect actual pair)

Comment: looks good, need to try in practical @gavr thanks